# How to set Go vanity import URL to repository subdirectory in a monorepo?

Tags: go

I'm working with a monorepo that is organized by language at the top level, so all Go modules are located in the `go` directory in the repository root. I want to set up a vanity import URL that points to the `go` directory rather than the repository root so that the `go/` does not need to be included in the import path.

Current file structure:

```
/
  go/
    module1/
    module2/
```

Desired import format:

```golang
import (
    "go.example.com/module1"
    "go.example.com/module2"
)
```

currently possible but **not** desired:

```golang
import (
    "go.example.com/go/module1"
    "go.example.com/go/module2"
)
```

According to the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths) the format for the `<meta>` element at `go.example.com` should be of the form:

```html
<meta name="go-import" content="import-prefix vcs repo-root">
```

So in this case I would have:

```html
<meta name="go-import" content="go.example.com git github.com/example/repo">
```

This translates the path following the `import-prefix` to a path relative to the root directory of the repository, so that `go.example.com/this/path` looks for the `this/path` directory in the repo. I would like instead for the path to be relative to the `go` directory in the repo instead of the repo root.

Is there any way to inform `go get` that the paths following `go.example.com` should be relative to `github.com/example/repo/go` rather than just `github.com/example/repo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, but there are workarounds.

From [this issue in golang/go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/33562):

> [...] there is currently no way for the HTTPS server to indicate that the module is offset by the prefix `src/go`, since that is not a part of the Go package path. This layout is just not going to work with the `go` command's built-in `git` support.

With the `go` command's built-in `git` support, import specs start with the URL of the repository and are followed by a path to the desired package. Therefore paths must be relative to the repository root. With a vanity import path you can make the path *longer* if desired, but not shorter (e.g. `example.com/pkg`).

So the following is the shortest possible import path without a workaround: `go.example.com/go/<module>`.

---

#### Workarounds

For the truly dedicated.

These involve a bit of setup and extra handling and might not be worth it just for the aesthetics of the import path.

There are two approaches I've worked out (and one semi-solution that probably won't work with a large number of modules). The first is setting up a module proxy. The second is creating another repo that copies from the `go` directory and importing from there.

##### Use `replace` in `go.mod`

This one is pretty simple, you can make the base import path anything you like and just `replace` it in the `go.mod` file.

Downside is this gets complicated to manage with many interdependent modules (as discussed in the linked article in the next section). Also feels less special and the burden is on the *importing* project to set up rather than the *imported* project.

##### Go Module Proxy

[This article](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-write-your-own-go-module-proxy-ed2d861c577a)([gist](https://gist.github.com/Ompluscator/9bd4b552b0bd900ddf3f24c011fd244f)) does a nice job explaining the approach.

`go get` uses the `GOPROXY` environment variable to decide where to look to find and resolve packages. The basic idea is to set up a proxy server that knows how to translate the public module name and get the relevant code from the actual repo, then put the URL of that server in the `GOPROXY` variable.

Extra care is needed with this approach for private modules/repositories as you'll have to handle authentication as well.

##### Copy Git Repository

The final approach is to copy the contents of the `go` directory to another repo, which can be automated with GitHub Actions or similar.

To preserve version tags (if used) and branches (although not commit hashes), you can use [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to rewrite history so that the `go` directory is actually the package root (and always has been): `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter go/`.

Then just set the vanity `go-import` tag to:

```html
<meta name="go-import" content="go.example.com git github.com/example/repo-go">
```

(where the original repo was `github.com/example/repo`).